# Is it safe to keep X509Certificate2 in memory?

Tags: c#, .net, x509certificate2

Is it safe to keep `X509Certificate2` object in memory for a long? It could contain the private key as well and is there any risk of private key exposure via a memory dump?

or is it recommended to load the `X509Certificate2` just before the use and dispose straight after you finished?

Comment: If there is a risk of exposure then the amount of time makes little difference. Reduce exposure by preventing suspicious apps from running as Admin, thereby preventing them getting debug rights and dumping the memory of your app

Comment: You should still dispose the object when you are finished with it, for memory conservation reasons. If that is the lifetime of your app then it's fine to keep it around. Otherwise make sure to use `finally` `using` or `Dispose` etc

Comment: Note that whoever has the permissions to take memory dumps is also usually powerful enough to reverse engineer your code and locate the actual certificate (and private key) in other ways. So before making any changes to your code, escalate to a security professional and perform code review/smoke test.

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks for your comment, but that doesn't answer the question. The amount of time it exposes may make a difference. and yes, you should dispose of the resource if you suppose to have it short-lived.

Comment: @LexLi You should not hardcode the certificate in your code at all. There are certificate vaults and you should load the certificate securely when you need it. My question is not that. Once you loaded the certificate onto a X509Certificate2, is there a risk of exposure? or does the X509Certificate2 handles it securely as a SecureString does.

Comment: Why might it make a difference? Either way as far as I remember `X509Certificate2` stores the private key using Windows cryptography functions, so the key is never in the process memory. I think every time an encryption or decryption is needed it moves into kernel mode to do it.